# Django Template not rendering database CharField attribute in the {% url %} definition

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template :

```
<a href="{% url x.content.url_internal_django_link  x.content.id %}"> 
  {{x.content.content}} </a>
```

x.content.url_django_link = "seek_detail" in the db
When i manually enter the url name in the template like this it shows no error-

```
  <a href="{% url seek_detail  x.content.id %}"> 
      {{x.content.content}} </a>
```

The model is :

```
class SoukFeedContent(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    url_internal_django_link = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
    link_id = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: hmm, you are referencing content.id and content.url_internal_django_link which would be character field, not a foreignkey?

Comment: The two content's might look a bit confusing but the ForeignKey is referencing this model (SoukFeedContent). the main problem seems to be  in the rendering of x.content.url_internal_django_link as a string

Answer (score 3):

the [`{% url %}`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1205) is a built in template tag that:

> Returns an absolute URL matching given
>   view with its parameters.

By passing it `x.content.url_internal_django_link`, you are telling it to look for a view named `url_internal_django_link` inside the x app defined in the content.py file. It isn't hitting the db for the string value.

You should probably just define an `get_absolute_url` method in your model and have your link as

**models.py:**

```
class SoukFeedContent(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    link_id = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True) 

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('seek_detail', [str(self.id)])
```

**template:** assuming that x.content is an instance of your SoukFeedContent Model

```
<a href="{{ x.content.get_absolute_url }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django 1.3 release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi).

This can be written as follows in django 1.3:

```
{% load url from future %}

<a href="{% url x.content.url_internal_django_link  x.content.id %}"> 
      {{x.content.content}} </a>
```